# Matplotlib hatch does not work after update to version 2.1.2

Tags: python, matplotlib, radar-chart

I updated matplotlib from version 2.0.0 to 2.1.2 and my hatches do not display anymore. 
For convenience I take the same example I posted in my previous question ([Axis label hidden by axis in plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46242088/axis-label-hidden-by-axis-in-plot))

If I run this code in my python environment (python 3.5.2) with the older version of matloblib it displays the hatch, after the upgrade of matplotlib it does not. How can I still display the hatch?

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random

data = random.sample(range(100), 5)
data[0] = 100
data[3] = 50
index = ['industry', 'residential', 'agriculture', 'transport', 'other']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=['data'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array(data)/2, index=index, columns=['data'])

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="polar")

ax.grid(True)
ax.yaxis.grid(color='r')  
ax.xaxis.grid(color='#dddddd')  

for spine in ax.spines.values():
    spine.set_edgecolor('None')

theta = np.arange(len(df1))/float(len(df1))*2.*np.pi

l1, = ax.plot(theta, df1["data"], color="gold", marker="o", label=None, zorder=1)  # , zorder = -3)
l2, = ax.plot(theta, df2["data"], color='tomato', marker="o", label=None, zorder=1.1)  #, zorder =-2)

def _closeline(line):
    x, y = line.get_data()
    x = np.concatenate((x, [x[0]]))
    y = np.concatenate((y, [y[0]]))
    line.set_data(x, y)
[_closeline(l) for l in [l1, l2]]

mpl.rcParams['hatch.color'] = 'red'
ax.fill(theta, df1["data"], edgecolor="gold", alpha=1, color = 'None', zorder=1)
ax.fill(theta, df2["data"], edgecolor='tomato', hatch='///', color = 'None', zorder=2)

ax.set_rlabel_position(216)
ax.set_xticks(theta)
ax.set_xticklabels(df2.index, fontsize=12)#, zorder=1)
for it in np.arange(len(theta)):   
    txt = ax.text(theta[it], 100*1.1, index[it], va = 'center', ha = 'center', fontsize = 12)

ax.set_xticklabels('')
legend = plt.legend(handles=[l1,l2], labels =['first','second'], loc='lower right')

plt.title("data [unit]", fontsize = 16, y = 1.2)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you clearly state what the desired outcome is, or how it did look in the previous version compared to how it looks now? There are some colors red, gold, "None" involved, but which part should be colororized how?

Comment: There should be a hatched filling inside the inner figure (which displays fine with the old version of matplolib, without changing my code)

Comment: I understand that. But what I'm asking is how exactly do you want the patch to look like (there seems to be some contradiction between edgecolor and "hatch.color"). Just describe how it should look like independed of the fact that some code produced some other result in some previous version.

Comment: I will post a picture on Monday. But I should see slanted red lines in the centre figure.. Sort of like this ///

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a hatched area in matplotlib with no background, you may set `fill=False`.

```
ax.fill(..., hatch='///', edgecolor="gold", fill=False)
```

Complete example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0, 0], [1, 0.2], [1, 1.2], [0, 1.]])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.fill(a[:,0],a[:,1], hatch='///', edgecolor="gold", alpha=1, fill=False)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Cheers! it worked, I changed the second fill to `ax.fill(theta, df2["data"],  hatch='///', alpha=1, edgecolor = 'tomato', fill = False, zorder=2)`